# iOS: -[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, nsdictionary

This is the following code I have

```
   id dataDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                               propertyListWithData:[dictionaryStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                               options:kNilOptions
                               format:NULL
                               error:NULL];

  if ([dataDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { 
       for (NSString *key in dataDict) {
          // value string crashes with the following exception -[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: 
           NSString *value = [dataDict objectForKey:key];
     }
 }
```

There is a user who is having a crash occur on the following line `NSString *value = [dataDict objectForKey:key];` according to crashlytics. This doesn't make any sense to me because I check beforehand if dataDict belongs to the NSDictionary class. Can someone please explain to me how I can prevent this crash?

Comment: it should be either  for (NSString *key in dataDict.allKeys) or for(id key in dataDict) {

Comment: This has to be some kind of red herring...